# listview listitem size increase with respects of android phone and tablet

Tags: android, listview

i am creating a listview with custom arrayadapter..but the problem is in tablet it's showing the listitem is very small.. can any1 help me,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to make the width of the listview fixed. you can do it in the corresponding layout xml file. there you add property like `android:layout_width="200dp"`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue remove static variables ie, fixed values. Create dynamic xmls with fill_parent, match_parent.

Thanks...